# I want my money to be private and to use it as needed each month to pay bills etc

Tags: exchange, transactions, payment, account, merchants

How do I get a Monero account?  What is the transition process from a bank account to Monero?  Do I transfer my bank account to a Monero account?  Or do I write a check?  Do I pay my bills with electronic Monero funds?  I really dont understand how I use Monero funds to pay bills.  This is new to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I like your intentions.  But that's not really going to happen, for a long time, if ever.
As with all cryptocurrencies, the vendor, shop, utility, landlord, etc need to accept it.
There are ways to convert the cryptocurrencies to your local money, and/or to send that to a payee.  But they will give a bad exchange rate and add fees on top of that.

In a nutshell cryptocurrencies are LONG way away from being ready for everyday use.  It's the fault of the vendors not accepting it, and mostly because of the volatility of the value of the cryptocurrencies (which is why so few do accept it).